# Submitting multiple form values with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an php/mysql inventory system that displays multiple items using a while loop. Every time an item is displayed I have an input text box associated with each item for the purpose of changing the quantity of that item.

I'm trying to include a submit button that will post multiple values to another php page to change all the item quantities for all items that I have entered a new quantity into its associated input text box. Basically I'm trying to avoid updating item quantities one at a time. I'd like to do it all in one pass. This is the form that exists in the while loop that gets associated to each item.

```
 <form name="qty" method="post" action="<?php echo "change_qty.php?id=".$cards['id']?>">
 <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="qty" autocomplete="off" size = "5px" />
 <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
 <input type='submit' name='qty' value='Update All Quantities'/>
 </form>
```

The form is post to qty. Would $_POST be an array of all the qty values then when the form is submitted?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards
Jack

Comment: I don't understand, but you should use different names for the text box and the submit button.

Comment: Sry, Wat is u r need ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: basically the while loop displays an input text box for each item. I want a form that passes each of the inputted text box values to another page so that I can change multiple values at one rather than submitting one value at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, this would involve having forms within forms, which isn't allowed in php. Now if you wanted a form that Just submitted all of them, and assuming that you know how many items you can have.

```
<?php while($cards = $result.hasNext()){ ?>
<form name="qty" method="post" action="<?php echo "change_qty.php?id=".$cards['id']?>">
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $cars['id']; ?>" placeholder="qty" autocomplete="off" size = "5px" />
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>
<?php } ?>

<input type='submit' value='Update All Quantities'/>
</form>
```

This will print your ids 101, 102 ... etc. Then you can call these from your change_qty.php in a loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<maxId; i++){
    //UPDATE query and anything else you want to do with it
}
```